# .NET 5 - web.config for uploading large files - Azure App Services

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, web-config, .net-5

To allow large file uploads, the below config is required as a minimum in `web.config`.

.NET 5/Core doesn’t have a `web.config` at the time of development.

Is there any way to write the below config to `web.config` via Azure Pipelines in any automated way?

Direct configuration in the Azure App Service is not an option as we deploy the code multiple times per week.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000" />
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    <system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: ".NET 5/Core doesnt have web.config at the time of development." - correct, but Azure App Services use IIS, and IIS uses web.config (everything under `<system.webServer>` is IIS-related, not ASP.NET or .NET). (I appreciate it's confusing _and weird_ that both IIS and ASP.NET (but not ASP.NET Core) share the exact same configuration files - blame misguided decisions made 20 years ago).

Comment: I completely understand that - is there any way for azure pipeline to update/modify the config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit your `web.config` in your CI/CD pipeline, I would recommend taking a look at the [`File Transform task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops%5D), which uses XML transformations.

XML transformations are a pain in my opinion, however, so you could also opt for doing a simple file overwrite using Powershell if you just want to set your `web.config` to the contents above.

Also - **why not just include the `web.config` file in your repository**? That way, you won't need any CI tasks if you just want a static file & it'll work as expected.

Comment: thanks Ermiya, including the static web.config in .net core project worked.

Answer (score 0):

Initially .NET 5/Core doesnt have **web.config** at the time of development , but after deployment web.config will be generated in your Azure App.

If you want you can include the web.config file in your repository before deploying.

You can view your files in Portal.

1. In the Azure Portal, navigate to the web app.
2. In the  **App Service**  blade, enter  **kudu**  in the search box.
3. Select  **Advanced Tools**  >  **Go**.
4. Select  **Debug console > CMD**.
5. Navigate to  *site/wwwroot*
6. Select the pencil icon to edit the  *web.config*  file.

[image]

Comment: have done this already, need to this in automated way via CI/CD ?